# Playframework 2 - creating a sql query

Tags: playframework-2.0

Im trying to create a simple query, for some reason all combinations i try, throws the following exception

> play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.RuntimeException: get uid on [models.User] type[java.lang.String] threw error.

I Have a User model and a Project model.
I want a query that searches for a project that belongs to user X and has name Y.

the code i tried that throws the exception above:

```
Project uploadProject = Project.find.where().add(Expr.and(Expr.eq("owner", curUser.email),Expr.eq("name", projectName))).findUnique();
```

also tried

```
Project uploadProject2 = Project.find.where().eq("owner", curUser.email).eq("name", projectName).findUnique();
```

what is the correct way to do this, I've searched in play documentation but it will only refer to simple searches none that require more then 1 parameter to search by.

Comment: Your query looks good Play uses [ebean](http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery.html) are you able to request the object with one query?

Comment: My bad, after 2 hours looking for solution in query, turns out the issue was with "owner" field is a User object. and i compared it to email `eq("owner", curUser.email)` should be `eq("owner.email", curUser.email)` ... i'm annoyed i found it 10 minutes after i post.. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception was due to comparing wrong field types.
owner field is of User type, i compared it to the user email string.

in my case

```
.eq("owner", curUser.email)
```

should of been:

```
.eq("owner.email", curUser.email)
```